# Encrypt Bluetooth Chat

Tags: android-studio, bluetooth

Having issues with the app, shuts down any time I click on the chat button. I just submitted my manifest, gradle , xml, and the mainactivity to check what really went wrong. Thanks

I have an error from the logcat
GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1.

So I don't know if this is the reason why it keeps shutting down any time I tap the button chat. The button chat is created in an activity.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="c.bawp.securemessenger">
    
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    
    
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.SecureMessenger">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
            <activity android:name=".ChooseActivity" >
    
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    
            <activity android:name=".FileExchangeActivity"></activity>
        </application>
    
    </manifest>




package c.bawp.securemessenger;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private TextView status;
        private Button btnConnect;
        private ListView listView;
        private Dialog dialog;
        private TextInputLayout inputLayout;
        private MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> chatAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> chatMessages;

        private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

        public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
        public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
        public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
        public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_OBJECT = 4;
        public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;
        public static final String DEVICE_OBJECT =  "device_name";

        private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 1;
        private ChatController chatController;
        private BluetoothDevice connectingDevice;
        private ArrayAdapter<String> discoveredDevicesAdapter;
        private Encrypt encrypt;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewsByIds();

        //check device support bluetooth or not
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

        //show bluetooth devices dialog when click connect button
        btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                showPrinterPickDialog();
            }
        });

        //set chat adapter
        messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this);
        listView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);

        encrypt = new Encrypt();
    }

    private final Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case ChatController.STATE_CONNECTED:
                            setStatus("Connected to: " + connectingDevice.getName());
                            btnConnect.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            break;
                        case ChatController.STATE_CONNECTING:
                            setStatus("Connecting...");
                            //btnConnect.setEnabled(false);
                            break;
                        case ChatController.STATE_LISTEN:
                        case ChatController.STATE_NONE:
                            setStatus("Not connected");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                    byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                    String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                    writeMessage = encrypt.decrypt(writeMessage);
                    //check out
                    MemberData data1 = new MemberData("Me","#C62828");
                    c.bawp.securemessenger.Message message1 = new c.bawp.securemessenger.Message(writeMessage, data1, true);
                    messageAdapter.add(message1);
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                    String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                    readMessage = encrypt.decrypt(readMessage);
                    MemberData data2 = new MemberData(connectingDevice.getName(),"#C62828");
                    Log.d("Bug", "handleMessage: " + readMessage);
                    c.bawp.securemessenger.Message message2 = new c.bawp.securemessenger.Message(readMessage, data2, false);
                    messageAdapter.add(message2);
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_DEVICE_OBJECT:
                    connectingDevice = msg.getData().getParcelable(DEVICE_OBJECT);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to " + connectingDevice.getName(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString("toast"),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    private void showPrinterPickDialog() {
        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_bluetooth);
        dialog.setTitle("Bluetooth Devices");


        if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

        //Initializing bluetooth adapters
        ArrayAdapter<String> pairedDevicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        discoveredDevicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        //locate listviews and attach the adapters
        ListView listView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.pairedDeviceList);
        ListView listView2 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.discoveredDeviceList);
        listView.setAdapter(pairedDevicesAdapter);
        listView2.setAdapter(discoveredDevicesAdapter);

        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        registerReceiver(discoveryFinishReceiver, filter);

        // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished


        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        // If there are paired devices, add each one to the ArrayAdapter
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                pairedDevicesAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        } else {
            pairedDevicesAdapter.add(getString(R.string.none_paired));
        }

        //Handling listview item click event
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

                connectToDevice(address);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });

        listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

                connectToDevice(address);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
    }


    private void setStatus(String s) {

        status.setText(s);
    }

    private void connectToDevice(String deviceAddress) {
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
        chatController.connect(device);
    }


    private void findViewsByIds() {

        status = findViewById(R.id.status);
        btnConnect = findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.list);
        inputLayout = findViewById(R.id.input_layout);
        Button btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btn_send);

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (Objects.requireNonNull(inputLayout.getEditText()).getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please input some texts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    //TODO: here
                    sendMessage(inputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString());
                    inputLayout.getEditText().setText("");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                chatController = new ChatController(this, handler);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth still disabled, turn off application!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (chatController.getState() != ChatController.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Connection was lost!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if (message.length() > 0) {
            message = encrypt.encrypt(message);
            byte[] send = message.getBytes();
            chatController.write(send);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {


            Intent dIntent =  new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            dIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 3000);
            startActivity(dIntent);

        } else {
            chatController = new ChatController(this, handler);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (chatController != null) {
            if (chatController.getState() == ChatController.STATE_NONE) {
                chatController.start();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (chatController != null)
            chatController.stop();
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver discoveryFinishReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
                if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    discoveredDevicesAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                }
                // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                discoveredDevicesAdapter.clear();
                //setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                // setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

                setTitle("Select a device to connect");
                if (discoveredDevicesAdapter.getCount() == 0) {

                    discoveredDevicesAdapter.add("No devices found");
                }
            } else {
                discoveredDevicesAdapter.add("Scanning Bluetooth Devices....");
            }
        }


    };

}
```